# How does one handle the submit event for a search bar?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Fair warning, this is a rather noob-ish question, but I couldn't find a proper answer here, in the Ionic docs, or the Angular docs. Here are a couple of places I've looked (not listed are StackOverflow pages without answers or using a different framework):

- [ion-searchbar - Ionic Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar#events)
- [Angular - Property binding](https://angular.io/guide/property-binding)

I am having trouble creating a search bar that navigates to another page on submit. I'd like to accomplish this without the use of a button (for aesthetic/UI/UX reasons), but I notice in the Ionic docs that there is no "submit" event defined for the `ion-searchbar` component. So I used `keyup.enter` instead, but I worry that on mobile, the event might not be triggered by hitting "Enter", "Submit", etc. an on-screen keyboard. Will this work?

Also, I am having trouble capturing the input value. When I hit enter (on desktop), I capture a [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) (which doesn't include the text value), not a [`CustomEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) as emitted by `ionChange`, for example (which includes the value). Since no text value is captured, the page transitions to an empty results page.

One thing I tried was binding the `ionChange` event to a method that updates `this.value`, which worked in some cases, but there was a race condition. If I waited a second, the value would be passed successfully as a URL parameter, but if I typed it quickly, the keyboard event (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) would be triggered before the text change event, and an empty string would be passed to `.navigate()`.

I think the right solution is to bind the `value` property in the searchbar to the `value` property in the component, but I haven't had any success with that, either. This example will always pass an empty string to the Router.

*home.page.html*

```html
<ion-searchbar [value]="value" (keydown.enter)="onSubmit($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

*home.page.ts*

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  value = '';

  constructor(private _router: Router) {}

  onSubmit($event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    console.log($event);
    console.log(this.value);
    this._router.navigate(['word', this.value]);
  }
}
```

What changes should I make to this example to achieve my intended behavior?

#### Edit

This is my attempt with the data race:

*home.page.html*

```html
<ion-searchbar (ionChange)="onChange($event)" (keydown.enter)="onSubmit($event)">
```

*home.page.ts*

```js
onChange($event: CustomEvent): void {
  this.value = $event.detail.value;
}

onSubmit($event: KeyboardEvent): void {
  console.log($event);
  console.log(this.value);
  this._router.navigate(['word', this.value]);
}
```

Comment: `(ionInput)="yourFunction($event)"` try this event on your `ion-searchbar`

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib This has a similar functionality to `ionChange`, but the problem is I can't capture the enter key that way. So I can have separate event bindings for (`ionChange` or `ionInput`) and `keydown.enter`, but I still run into that race condition I described.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Btw, `ionInput` provides single key press values, while `ionChange` provides the whole string, so I'm more inclined to use the latter.